# Simple variance of estimator calculation question

Tags: self-study, variance, bias

I'm trying to solve a question about finding bias and variance of an estimator, but I'm having trouble with the variance calculation.

Say we have an IID sample of n points $y_i \sim  N(\mu,1)$.

If we then use an estimator $\hat\mu=1$, we can compute the variance as $Var[\hat\mu] = E[(\hat\mu - E[\hat\mu])^2] = E[(1-E[1])^2] = E[0^2] = 0$

But then if we have an estimator $\hat\mu=y_1$, then the variance should be $Var[\hat\mu] = E[(\hat\mu - E[\hat\mu])^2] = E[(y_1 - E[y_1])^2] = E[(y_1 -\mu)^2]$ And then I didn't know what to do from there.

The solution, however said that you could just do $Var[\hat\mu] = Var[y_1] = 1$.
This seemed to make sense, but then I tried to use this same method for the first estimator: $Var[\hat\mu] = Var[1] = 1$. But this should be 0, so this didn't work.

So can someone explain what the proper way to do these two are? And why does the second way not work for the first estimator ($\hat\mu=1$)?

Comment: What is your definition of variance?  I have to ask, because for many people the variance of $y_1$ is *defined* by your expression $E[(y_1-\mu)^2]$; and so for them you're immediately done because you at the outset you stated $y_1$ has a variance of $1$.  If there's any question left to be answered, then, it must be because you are using some other definition of variance--but what is it? Incidentally, there is an error lurking at the end: $\operatorname{Var}[1]$ is $0$, not $1$.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you're right, I didn't even realize I was looking at the definition of variance. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
Case 1:
when your $\hat{u}$ = 1
Then, Var($\hat{u}$) = Var(1) = E$(1 - E(1))^2$ = E$(1-1)^2$ = E(0) = 0
Infact, a variance of constant term is always 0 not 1.
Case 2 :
when your $\hat{u}$ =  $y_1$
Since it is mentioned that $y_1$ ~ N($\mu$,1),this means that var($y_1$) = 1
Thus, var($\hat{u}$) = var($y_1$) = 1.
One more point,in your approach you mentioned that you were stuck at E($y_1$-$\mu$)$^2$,actually it is nothing but $var(y_1)$

Comment: Oh wow, you're right, I totally forgot to think about the variance of a constant. I also forgot that like your last point said, I had the definition of $var(y_1)$ right there. Thanks!